# Как сделать зависимые ячейки с чекбоксами доступными для изменения их состояния вручную?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, таблицы

Есть таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ячейка A1 содержит независимый чекбокс:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ячейки A2:A6 содержит формулу =ЕСЛИ(A1;ИСТИНА;""):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача следующая: нужно сделать так, чтобы при установке флажка в ячейке A1 ячейки из интервала A2:A6 также принимали значение ИСТИНА (автоматически устанавливался флажок), но если в ячейке A1 не установлен флажок (значение ЛОЖЬ), то в ячейках из диапазона A2:A6 оставалась возможность ручного изменения состояния.

Первое условие работает, но вот со вторым проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Формулой сделать этого нельзя.** Просто потому, что, согласно высказанным требованиям, результат вычислений для A2:A6 должен зависеть не только от значения в ячейке A1, но и от значений A2:A6, которые выбирает пользователь. То есть искомая формула заведомо содержит циклическую ссылку и неизбежно выдаст ошибку.

Альтернативу следует искать в скриптах, обрабатывающих событие изменения данных в ячейке пользователем. Для этого и создан [триггер onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers?hl=en#onedite). Здесь подойдет следующий код:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  // Проверяем, что пользователем изменены интересующие нас ячейки 
  if (sheet.getName() != 'My Sheet') return;
  var notation = e.range.getA1Notation();
  if (notation == 'A1' && e.value == 'TRUE') {
    // Все нижеследующие ячейки получают установку флажков
    sheet.getRange('A2:A6').setValues([[true], [true], [true], [true], [true]]);
  } else if (['A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6'].indexOf(notation) > -1) {
    // Зафиксирована попытка изменить значение в ячейках A2:A6
    // Ее нужно пресечь в том случае, если в A1 установлен флажок
    if (sheet.getRange('A1').getValue() == true) e.range.setValue(e.oldValue);
  }
}
```

Обратите внимание на то, как скрипт фильтрует события, относящиеся именно к требуемому листу (с именем "My Sheet") и к требуемым ячейкам этого листа. И эта проверка - все еще не полная, потому что гипотетически пользователь может изменить ячейки, например, копированием диапазона. Однако, такие специфические действия пользователя - не тема вопроса, так что здесь на них останавливаться не будем.